# ProLiant DL380 G4 ESXi host - How to check RAID status of local storage

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, smart

In a data center we have a few ESXi hosts. We're migrating all the data off the machines, but first we would like to check the RAID/SMART status of the local drives.

Is there any way to do this via ILO without a restart?

Comment: Have you used the HP build for the ESXi? The info which appears on VMware's site: HP ESXi Installable CD for ESXi 4.1 Update 1 04/12/11  |  4.1 Update 1  |  431 MB  |  Binary (.iso)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to check the RAID status on that model using ESXi. Even the HP-build of ESXi won't provide status on that generation of server.